How to reset keycloak admin password
import kcAdminClient from '../components/keycloak_clients.mjs';
import { Issuer } from 'openid-client';
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()


like this I import keycloak. here below is the error.
node:internal/process/promises:288 triggerUncaughtException(err,
true /* fromPromise */); ^ [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error
originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a
catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with
.catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "AxiosError: Request
failed with status code 401".] { code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION' }

------------------------------------------------------------------------2. I find that admin password set in env is wrong. How to rest keycloak admin password. Actually I installed keycloak in windows

I recommend including the whole error stack trace and an example of your code snippet in a code block on where you're seeing the issue so we can help you more.

added the whole error

Do you have any axios related code? Looks like this is related to something totally different then the code block you've provided. Your axios call seems to not be able to make its request and is getting a http status code of 401, meaning unauthorized.

It is because wrong admin password set in env. how to reset keycloak admin paswword?

You can reset master admin's password by REST API
PUT /admin/realms/master/users/{admin user id}/reset-password

Body of JSON input
{
    "temporary": false,
    "type": "password",
    "value": "New password"
}

Demo
Old password is "admin"
New password is "1234"
launch Keycloak v24.2
Run by docker-compose in here
Save as demo.js
const axios = require('axios')
const querystring = require('querystring')

const getToken = async (password) => {
    try {
        const requestObject= querystring.stringify({
            grant_type: "client_credentials",
            client_id: "admin-cli",
            username: "admin",
            password: password,
            grant_type: "password"
        })
        const config = {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              "Accept":"*/*",
            }
        }
        const resp = await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token',
            data: requestObject,
            headers: config.headers})

        return Promise.resolve(resp.data.access_token)
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
}

const getUserId = async (master_token, user_name) => {
    try {
        const siteUrl = `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/master/users/?username=${user_name}`
        const response = await axios.get(siteUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${master_token}`
            }
        });
        return Promise.resolve(response.data[0].id)

    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
}

const resetPassword = async (master_token, user_id, new_password) => {
    try {
        const url = `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/master/users/${user_id}/reset-password`
        const body = {
            temporary: false,
            type: "password",
            value: new_password
        }
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${master_token}`
            }
        }
        await axios.put(url, body, config)
        console.log(`Password for user ID ${user_id} reset successfully`)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error resetting password for user ID ${user_id}: ${error}`)
        throw error
    }
}

(async () => {
    const old_password = 'admin'
    const master_token = await getToken(old_password)
    console.log('master_token: ' + JSON.stringify(master_token))
    const user_name = 'admin'
    const user_id = await getUserId(master_token, user_name)
    console.log(user_name +'\'s ' + 'user_id: ' + user_id)
    
    const new_password = '1234' // Define your new password here
    await resetPassword(master_token, user_id, new_password)
})()

Install dependencies
npm install axios querystring

Run it
node demo.js

Result
New password is changed without error.

